# ADO Recordset returns nothing

Tags: mysql, vb.net, ado

I am accessing a MySQL table with ADO Recorset, however the ADO Recordset does not return records. I am using VB.NET in Visual Studio. I can establish communication with the database, make the connection, create tables, all via connection object (as below) but at the time of returning the information via Recordset, gives error.

```
Dim conn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim fld As ADODB.Field
Dim aux As String

aux = "Provider = MSDASQL;Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.2 ANSI Driver}; Server=localhost; Database = db-teste; User=root; Password=123456; Option=3;"
conn.Open(aux)

'create table
conn.Execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_ado")
conn.Execute("CREATE TABLE my_ado(id int Not null primary key, name varchar(20)," &
                "txt text, dt date, tm time, ts timestamp)")
'insert
conn.Execute("INSERT INTO my_ado(id,name,txt) values(1,100,'venu')")
conn.Execute("INSERT INTO my_ado(id,name,txt) values(2,200,'MySQL')")

'============================================================================
' UNTIL HERE, IT WORKS FINE!
'============================================================================


' This does not get anything
rs.Open("SELECT * FROM my_ado", conn)
rs.MoveFirst()

' RecordCount always returns "-1" <<<<<<====================
Debug.Print(Str(rs.RecordCount()))

' rs.Fields = ERROR
For Each fld In rs.Fields 
    Debug.Print(fld.Name)
Next
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Check the database configuration to ensure that the AUTO COMMIT switch is turned on, otherwise you need to commit the data.  I'm not entirely familiar with MySQL, but I know INSERT needs to be committed one way or the other.

This post explains everything:

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/4252/do-inserts-get-auto-committed

Add this to your code after the `rs.Open("SELECT * FROM my_ado", conn)` line of code:

```
' Create dataset and data adapter objects
Dim ds As New DataSet("Recordset")
Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter()

' Call data adapter's Fill method to fill data from ADO
' Recordset to the dataset

da.Fill(ds, rs, "Data")
```

The data should be in `ds.Tables!Data`, you can check with this line:

```
ds.Tables!Data.Rows.Count
```

Comment: Thanks, but it's another problema I think... when i run `conn.Execute()`, ADOconnection execute commit automatically, so this way it's not necessary to make a `conn.CommitTrans()`. If i do `conn.CommitTrans()`, it'll throw a error "No active transactions"

Comment: Can you access the database and dump out the table "manually"?  Also, might be nothing, but the name of the table columns implies that the NAME column is a string as in my name, but the value is numeric, just an observation.  Shouldn't generate an error as an implicit conversion should convert it.

Comment: Yes, I can access table. The values of that column are numerics, but when I get value it converted by "ToString". I've tried to access another table and others columns types. It was the same problem... thanks

Comment: Sorry for what I'm going to ask, but by chance do you have a ready and working example that has been tested in VB.NET?

Comment: I use a Oracle Datatbase backend, it's been a very long time since I've used ADODB for anything.  I may have some old code hanging around, if I can find it I'll post it.

Comment: Sorry, all I have is some old OLEDB code that reads a spreadsheet and saves the data to the database.

Comment: OK. Using OLEDB also worked well with me. My problem is only with the ADODB Recordset, that I still don't understand why recordset doesn't return anything.. It looks like correct syntax, but it doesn't works. Thanks for your attention.